# How to modify clipboard paste data on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I meet a requirement,the user can copy data from any other resources(such as word,excel,notepad++),and then paste it to my web page,the application must be run on Chrome. I have to modify the paste data if it contains some invalid data.

I tried *clipboardData.setData* but it only work on **IE**,below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elEditor = document.getElementById("editor");

elEditor.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
    var clipboardData = e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    var text = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    console.log("---before:\t"+text);
    text = text.replace(/\d+/,new Date().getTime());
    //don't change the pasted data on Chrome page!That's the key point make it fail
    clipboardData.setData('Text',text);
    console.log("---after:\t"+text);
    return false;
});

</script>
```

I can see the data in Chrome console changed,but in the web page,the data is still not changed!Can anyone help me?

If not use **clipboardData.setData**,is there any other ways can do the same thing?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the 'paste' event, you need to change the content of the field, because the paste has already happened;

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/75276/

```
        $('.cpf_cnpj').each(function(){
            $(this).on('paste', function(e){

              var clipboardData = e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
              if (clipboardData){ 
                    var text = clipboardData.getData('text');
                    text = text.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/-/g, '').replace(/\//g, '');            
                    e.target.value = text;
                    e.preventDefault();                     
              }
            });
        });
```

Comment: That is not true. The event for paste has not already happened. This makes `cmd` + `z` and `ctrl` + `z` not work.

Comment: For me it works fine. When I paste the text to textarea it has the special characters removed.